# Dificuldade em gravar 3 input com name diferentes com foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou criando um carrinho de compras e preciso gravar via form os produtos selecionados pelo cliente. Esta quase tudo funcionando, faltando apenas gravar os produtos na tabela itemvenda.

Eu fiz esse foreach abaixo para listar os produtos com seus dados:

```
    <?php
    require("conexao.php");
    foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $carrinho){

    echo '<tr style="font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; color:#000;">       
          <input size="1" type="hidden" name="codproduto" value="'.$codigo.'" />
          <input size="1" type="hidden" name="quant" value="'.$qtd.'" />
          <input size="5" type="hidden" name="preco" value="'.$preco.'" />
          </tr>';

    ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Mas não consigo gravar mais do que 1 produto, se compro 2, 3 ou mais produtos, ele grava somente o ultimo da lista.

Estou publicando a baixo o `INSERT` usado para gravar os dados na tabela.

```
    <?php
    include '../conexao.php';

    if(isset($_POST['bb'])){

    $codvenda = mysql_insert_id();
    $codproduto = $_POST['codproduto'];
    $quant = $_POST['quant'];
    $preco = $_POST['preco'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO itemvenda (codvenda, codproduto, quant, preco) values ('$codvenda', '$codproduto', '$quant', '$preco')");
    }
    ?>
```

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma luz de como devo proceder para que possa gravar todos os produtos listados pelo foreach, ficarei agradecido.

Abraços à todos.

Comment: Como voce esta "inserindo"  os dados na super global $_SESSION ? pelo que parece voce esta inserindo uma string por vez! tente criar um array e guardar na super global.

Comment: Olá  Rafael Acioly, beleza? Você me mostrar como criar o array, pois sou iniciante em PHP, mas estou tentando aprender a trabalhar com ele.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi galera, foi feita alterações no INSERT, e ficou assim o código.

Página do INSERT:

```
$codvenda = mysql_insert_id();
$codproduto = $_REQUEST['codproduto']; 
$quant = $_REQUEST['quant']; 
$preco = $_REQUEST['preco']; 

for($i=0; $i<count($codproduto) AND ($quant) AND ($preco); $i++){   

$query_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO itemvenda (codvenda, codproduto, quant, preco) values ('$codvenda', '$codproduto[$i]', '$quant[$i]', '$preco[$i]')");
        //printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
}
```

E no Formulário foi acrescentado [] apos os nomes dos name nos input:

Formulário:

```
    echo '<tr style="font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; color:#000;">       
        <input size="1" type="hidden" name="codproduto[]" value="'.$codigo.'" />
        <input size="1" type="hidden" name="quant[]" value="'.$qtd.'" />
        <input size="5" type="hidden" name="preco[]" value="'.$preco.'" />
      </tr>';
```

Espero que a essa publicação possa ajudar a outros curiosos como eu a resolver esse tipo de problema.

Valeu pela atenção de todos, e grande abraço.